# Where can I find a review of discrete math

Tags: soft-question, reference-request, education, discrete-mathematics

I'm looking for course notes and assignments  and hopefully some example exams for Discrete Math, I'm taking a placement exam in the subject after having taken it 4 years ago.

Comment: What kind and what level of discrete math you are talking about? Combinatorics, graph theory, some elementary number theory? It's easier if you find reviews on each individual topic, discrete math is a large field.

Comment: I was looking mostly for the equivalent of a first course in Discrete Mathematics. The usual content if I remember correctly was basically just a overview of everything you mentioned. Logic, Proof Techniques(induction), Number Theory, Sets, Abstract Algebra, Graph theory...  Nothing in depth but just an overview of it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the discrete math course one in my school. It contain lecture notes, homework and previous exams. http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~cse547/

Answer (score 3):

When wanting to know about a particular mathematics subject, I often find that starting with the "[further reading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_mathematics#Further_reading)" section of the relevant wikipedia page is a good way in.

Answer (score 2):

if you don't mind shell out a good amount of money, *Concrete Mathematics* by Graham, Knuth and Patashnik could be nice (I own the first edition)

Comment: That is well beyond discrete mathematics, at least what is taught in discrete mathematics at the undergraduate level at my university.

Comment: @Thomas: I second that, you can get depressed by this book as it really for advanced students (pretty good at math). Its certainly a GEM but not the right tool for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to textbooks, the Kenneth Rosen text [Discrete Mathematics and its Applications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0073229725) is highly recommended. I was first introduced to it at my university, but I've seen it cited in several places.

Comment: Good book suggestion, I have a copy of the book from the last time I took the course, I was just hoping to find material that would let me check what I remember and then be able to dive into what I forgot by reading the book section needed.

Comment: In terms of assignments, we just worked problems right from the book. And most of the test problems were either from the book or based on problems in the book. I would suggest just doing that - reading the chapter and picking out a few questions and checking your work and answers with the solution guide. Unfortunately, I can't provide you with links to the material from when I took the course - they aren't on any public web pages. :(

Answer (score 0):

For quick review Schaum's Discrete Mathematics is good.

If you have time, read **Foundations of Computer Science** By Aho-Ullman. It's free and available online. Around 800 pages.