# Free resources to start learning Discrete Mathematics

Tags: reference-request, discrete-mathematics

Can anyone recommend good, free online articles or books to learn Discrete mathematics? When I google'd for them, I came across few resources..but don't know whether they are good to start learning with. It's better to know a tutorial or a book that get you started in Discrete Mathematics. Can readers of SE Mathematics can suggest a good starting point?

Comment: Discrete math is a huge subject.  Anything in particular?  Also, have you tried http://mathonline.andreaferretti.it/ ?

Comment: Thanks for the link..And I'm interested in topics which is more towards Theoretical Computer Science.

Comment: See the suggestions given in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1533/what-is-the-best-book-for-studying-discrete-mathematics and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350/where-can-i-find-a-review-of-discrete-math.

Comment: This question is actually a superset of the first question I linked to above, so perhaps that one (about books) should be considered a duplicate of this?

Answer (score 3):

The UVic Discrete Mathematics Study Guide is also good for concise notes on the basics:

http://www.math.uvic.ca/faculty/gmacgill/guide/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Try MIT Open Courseware -- Course 6.042J (Mathematics for Computer Science) on http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/ would be a good place to start.