# Discrete maths fundamentals

Tags: big-list, reference-request

Which is a good book to refresh discrete maths fundamentals for a grad student?

It would be great if the book has short and terse explanations of concepts with lots of worked out examples(/to be worked out exercises) to set the brain rolling.

Can someone suggest a similar refresher for graduate level algorithms?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3253/what-books-should-everyone-read

Comment: Possible duplicate:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1533/what-is-the-best-book-for-studying-discrete-mathematics  and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350/where-can-i-find-a-review-of-discrete-math

Answer (score 2):

Concrete Mathematics by Knuth is useful as a refresher AFAIK. But this is not a research level question so not really belongs here :).

Answer (score 1):

[Kleinberg and Tardos](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321295358) is a good book. I followed this book for an Introductory Graduate Discrete Mathematics course. It starts from basics and covers a good amount of material in depth. Kleinberg and Tardos has a lot of Exercises at the end of each chapter.

[Algorithms](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~vazirani/algorithms.html) book by S. Dasgupta, C.H. Papadimitriou, and U.V. Vazirani is an equally good book and is probably well-written than Kleinberg and Tardos. I have not read this book completely though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a graduate textbook, but I really like the discrete math [book](http://books.google.com/books?id=I6wxfY2dUwQC&) by Matousek and Nesetril.  It presents the topics more succinctly than the standard discrete math undergraduate texts and has much more interesting exercises.