# Where can I find (download) a book about basics of discrete mathematics?

Tags: reference-request, discrete-mathematics, learning

I am a beginner in this craft. Do you know where can I download a good book about basics of discrete mathematics?

Comment: What are your prerequisites? What do you need to learn?

Comment: This question has already been asked: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/350/19379, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1533/19379, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/5126/19379.

Comment: Just in case someone would consider vote-duplicate, kindly note that OP asks for a **downloadable** book.

Comment: Do you have access to a library? (somewhat off the downloadable topic)

Comment: Try http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.042/spring12/mcs.pdf

Comment: Amazon has many downloadable texts on discrete mathematics, though of course not for free.

Answer (score 5):

László Lovász & Kati Vesztergombi, *Discrete Mathematics*, Lecture Notes, Yale University, Spring 1999, is available as a .ps file [here](http://www.cs.elte.hu/%7Elovasz/notes.html) and as a PDF [here](https://cims.nyu.edu/%7Eregev/teaching/discrete_math_fall_2005/dmbook.pdf). **18 April 2020:** The PDF is no longer available.
**16 August 2020** The link is updated. Now its working.

Edward A. Bender & S. Gill Williamson, *Foundations of Combinatorics with Applications*, is available in both formats [here](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/%7Eebender/CombText/).

Both have a strong emphasis on combinatorics, and both do a significant amount of graph theory. The Bender & Williamson is a bit more computer-science oriented and covers in greater depth some of the topics that they have in common; the Lovász & Vesztergombi covers some elementary number theory.